# python replace with capture group

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, batch-file

how can I change all instances of ".nmv-fas" to whatever is between the "title" tags?
Is this possible with python or is there a better way?

basically change:

this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>.rtpv05-tl</title>
</head>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.5.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.5.nmv-fas</a>
```

to this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>.rtpv05-tl</title>
</head>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.rtpv05-tl">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.rtpv05-tl</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.rtpv05-tl">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.rtpv05-tl</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.rtpv05-tl">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.rtpv05-tl</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.rtpv05-tl">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.rtpv05-tl</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.5.rtpv05-tl">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.5.rtpv05-tl</a>
```

Comment: Can we have the context of this? As in, are you editing a html file on the disk or something?

Comment: yea its just a local html file, but I have a bunch of them. Each file in the batch is exactly the same just a different title value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v text='.nmv-fas' '
    /<title>/ {title=$0; gsub(/<\/?title>/, "", title); replace=1}
    replace {gsub(text, title)}
    {print}
' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

awk does not have an "in-place" option like sed's `-i`

Of course, this is dependent on the title text being on the same line as the `<title>` tag. For safety, you should use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: It looks like just one command, so yes, it is in a bash file.

Comment: this is a bash command that you can paste to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the title out as a string using regex.  Assuming your html is in some string s:

```
import re
match = re.compile(r"<title>(.+)</title>",re.I|re.DOTALL)
title = match.group(1)
```

Then just do a string replace on the string s

```
s.replace(".nmv-fas",title)
```